# Display content of large text file in textarea using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, electron

Hellow everyone,

Since few times I try to display the content of a pretty large text file (~500 Mb to 1 Gb) in a HTML textarea, to be able in the futur to filter the content and search more fast the information I want.

I choose to use a NodeJS solution (with Electron) and use a "createReadStream" with pipe and event-stream from npm.

I have no problem to read the content but when it comes to display the content in my textarea it take a lot of time to display become totally blank.

Maybe I use in a wrong way the pipe or my textarea can't handle that much of data ?

here is the code.
Thank you in advance for your advice.

```js
const [input, textarea] = [
      document.querySelector("input[type=file]")
    , document.querySelector(".display-file")
  ];
 
const fs = require('fs')
, es = require('event-stream');
var data = []; 
 
streamFile = function(x, y) {
 
  var returnTxt = '';
  var readStream = fs
  .createReadStream(y,  {flags: 'r'})
  .pipe(es.split(/(\r?\n)/))
  .pipe(
    es
    .map(function(line, cb){
      cb(null, line);
 
        returnTxt += line;
        x.value = returnTxt;
 
  })
 
  .on('error', function(err){
      console.log('Error while reading file.', err);
  })
 
  .on('end', function(){
      console.log('Read entire file.');
 
    })
 
    );
 
}
 
input.onchange = () => {
 streamFile(textarea, input.files.path);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
      <input type='file' />
 
      <textarea name="data-textbox" class="display-file"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am fairly certain you are running into computational limits.  If you open up the performance tab of a dev tool kit in your browser I'm going to suspect you are going to see a vast amount being spent on placing the characters into the textarea.  I recommend breaking it into chunks.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation I will search how to break into chunk. If you have any recommendation on a good way to do it I take it. Thank you